# Show a hidden div with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have done a CSS for a hidden div.
I'm trying to show the div when a button is clicked, but I'm getting "null" on Mozilla debugger. Any tip to solve this? Thanks.

*Sorry if the code is so bad, im just learning a little on my free time.*

```
<script id="but1">

  function Show() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("box");
    ele.style.visibility= "visible" ;
  }
</script>

<button type="button" class="but1" id="but1" onclick="Show()">Start</button> 
<div class="box">
  <p class="clicked">Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use id="box" in html and `document.getElementById("box");` in js script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have element with `class`, not `id` you should use `document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0];` instead `document.getElementById("box");`

Comment: Would prefer document.querySelector('.box') over document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0] since one can change the selector at anytime without changing the function name itself. But just my taste :)

Comment: Yea, I agree with your concept, also prefer `querySelector` :) have used `getElementsByClassName` in my answer to highlight the difference between querying by `class` and by `id` - which was a gist of the issue

Comment: Hmm yes, I agree with you in this case.

Comment: You could add a note in your answer, to suggest using `querySelector` and explain it briefly.

Answer (score 1):

> I have done a CSS for a **hidden div**.

In that case, use `display:block` instead of `ele.style.visibility= "visible" ;`

Also, `box` is a *class* so *document.getElementById* wont work.

```
var ele = document.querySelector(".box");
ele.style.display= "block" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`, you are identifying the id and not the class